# Class memory heap/reference variable concept

Tags: .net, memory, reference, heap-memory, stack-memory

Suppose we have code:

```
Class A = new Class();
```

We know that `new Class()` is the object and hence it will go to the heap.

We know that the 'A' is a reference variable and 'new Class()' is the actual object. Where does A go, stack/heap? Is 'A' a value/reference type?

And where does 'new Class()' go stack/heap? Is it a value/reference type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` is actually a reference type while its value is an address (a reference of) a heap which contains your object. while `new class()` is neither value nor reference type because left hand side of a assignment is a data type and a data type is reference or value type not the actual data.

visual might make it clear for you:

> [image: visual]

Comment: I have read that stack=value type and heap=reference type. If we follow this, then the 'A' is a value type as it goes to stack. Isnt it?

Comment: I would recommend you to [read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) this.